# Tomcat changes value of system property on startup

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I am running Tomcat 8.5.61 on Java 8 and need to provide a system property for my application. Locally, I am on Windows and run Tomcat from Git Bash.

The most obvious approach I found is to set it in `setenv.sh` like this:

> `CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dsome.variable=/value/"`

The value for my property needs to be set with the slashes.

However, during startup, I see the following log, and the value observed by the application is as shown here, which fails the application:

> `26-Mar-2021 09:00:29.955 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dsome.variable=C:/Program Files/Git/value/`

Seems that somehow the value was changed to be a folder below the Git home folder. (That folder was maybe chosen because I started Tomcat from Git Bash?)

I did not find online any hint regarding this behaviour so far. How can it be explained, and how should I set my system property instead?